# Why is my Common Lisp Binary search tree function not working properly?

Tags: lisp, binary-tree, common-lisp, binary-search-tree

I have to create a lisp program capable of checking whether a binary search tree is in fact a BST.

This is what I have made:

```
(defun BST (lst)
  (if (null lst) nil
    (let ((curr (car lst)) (left (car (cdr lst))) (right (cdr (cdr lst)))) 
         (cond
             ((and (null left) (null right)) t)
             ((and (numberp (car left)) (> (car left) curr)) nil)
             ((and (numberp (car right)) (<= (car right) curr)) nil)
             ((null right) (BST left))
             ((null left) (BST right))
             (t (and (BST right) (BST left)))))))

(print (BST '(8 (3 (1 () ()) (6 (4 () ())(7 () ()))) (10 () (14 (13) ())))))
```

The result is t, however if I edit the 10 to something lower than 8, the result is still true. In fact, my function seems to completely ignore the right side of the tree and only reacts to changes in the 8 -> 3 -> 1 path. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How is an empty BST represented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is `(let ((right (cdr (cdr lst)) ...)`. Unlike `car`, `cdr` of a proper list is guaranteed to return a list. It returns the second cell of a cons, not the second item of a list. To use only `car` and `cdr`, you'll need to change it to `(let ((right (car (cdr (cdr lst))))) ...)` (written in plain textbox, unsure about matching of parentheses). It is a better idea to use `first`, `second` and `third`, to re-write it like: 
`(let ((curr (first lst)) (left (second lst) (right (third lst)) ...`.

And I do think there are better way to write code about BST, by making more sensible utility functions.

Comment: This ended up being the problem yes! my initial code did have flaws, since it didnt make sure that every single node on the left was smaller than the root node and same for the right side. I made a few changes and it worked properly!

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is with abstraction. There is none.

From looking at the `let` destructuring I'm guessing a node is made like this:

```
(defun node (value &optional left right)
  (list* value left right))

(node 1 (node 2) (node 4))
; ==> (1 (2 nil) 4 nil)
```

However the tree you are passing seem to be made with this:

```
(defun node (value &optional left right)
  (list value left right))

(node 1 (node 2) (node 4))
; ==> (1 (2 nil nil) (4 nil nil))
```

How you model a binary tree doesn't really matter. What matters is that all your code use the same model and not different ones. This can be done by making constructors and getters.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, *always define abstractions over consy structures unless you are talking explicitly about consy structures.*  This is really important.

In the case of BSTs you want a function to make a node, and then some accessors.  The accessors can be entirely generic.

```
(defgeneric make-bst-node-for-node (node value left right)
  ;; Make a node to serve as a child of NODE
  )

(defgeneric bst-node-value (node))

(defmethod bst-node-value ((node cons))
  (car node))

(defgeneric bst-node-left (node))

(defgeneric (setf bst-node-left) (new node))

(defgeneric bst-node-right (node))

(defgeneric (setf bst-node-right) (new node))

(defgeneric plausible-bst-node-p (maybe-node)
  ;; Is MAYBE-NODE basically plausible?
  (:method (maybe-node)
   (declare (ignorable maybe-node))
   nil))

(defgeneric bst-node-components (node)
  ;; Return the components of a node as multiple values
  (:method (node)
   (values (bst-node-value node)
           (bst-node-left node)
           (bst-node-right node))))

;;; Consy BST nodes
;;;
(defun make-consy-bst-node (value left right)
  ;; A consy BST looks like (val . (left . right)), where left & right
  ;; are either BSTs or null.
  `(,value . (,left . ,right)))

(defmethod make-bst-node-for-node ((node cons) value left right)
  (make-consy-bst-node value left right))

(defmethod bst-node-left ((node cons))
  (car (cdr node)))

(defmethod (setf bst-node-left) (new (node cons))
  (setf (car (cdr node)) new))

(defmethod bst-node-right ((node cons))
   (cdr (cdr node)))

(defmethod (setf bst-node-right) (new (node cons))
  (setf (cdr (cdr node)) new))

(defmethod plausible-bst-node-p ((maybe-node cons))
  (consp (cdr maybe-node)))

(defmethod bst-node-components ((node cons))
  ;; Efficiency hack (probably not worth it)
  (let ((lr (cdr node)))
    (values (car node) (car lr) (cdr lr))))
```

Note there is no way of changing the value of a node, because I don't think you ever need to do that.

With abstractions like this, anything which actually walks BSTs can do it in terms of them, rather than in the style of all the appalling 1960s Lisp code we've all had to wade through, which is entirely made of `(CAR (CDDR (CAR (CDAADR ...))))` and most of which was written in the last 20 years.

Additionally most of the code which *builds* BSTs does not need to know the respresentation of them: once you've made a root node, you can use `make-bst-node-for-node` to make children for it.

*And it is precisely because you did not define abstractions and as a result never sorted out what the structure should really be that you ran into trouble I think*: your code implicitly uses a representation which is like the above, but the tree you're feeding it implicitly uses a structure which is `(value left right)`: a *different* representation.

To make life easier I'll define a couple of functions which take a `(value left right)` representation, which is more readable but a little less efficient, and turn it into a `(value . (left . right))` one (note this doesn't use `make-bst-node-for-node`, because it predates it and I am lazy):

```
(defun make-consy-bst (value lb rb)
  ;; LB and RB are either null or are recursively processed
  (make-consy-bst-node value
                       (if lb
                           (make-consy-bst (first lb) (second lb) (third lb))
                         nil)
                       (if rb
                           (make-consy-bst (first rb) (second rb) (third rb))
                         nil)))

(defun make-consy-bst* (thing)
  (apply #'make-consy-bst thing))
```

Now what you want is a function which, given something that purports to be a BST checks that it is.  Well, here is such a function.  Note that this function itself uses the abstractions above: there's no explicit car/cdr chasing here.  This means it will work for any kind of BST at all.  Note also that the implementation of this function is mildly devious: it use a slightly dirty trick of a recursive function which, if it finds something bad, returns directly from its parent.

Finally note also that this function is agnostic about what the values are: you can hand it a predicate which tells you if the values are legal and an ordering predicate.

```
(defun bst-p (maybe-bst &key
                        (value-predicate #'realp)
                        (comparison-predicate #'<))
  ;; Return two values: either T and the BST, or NIL and the first
  ;; object which failed to be a BST.
  (labels ((maybe-bst-value (thing)
             ;; Return the value of THING if it is a good BST.
             ;; If it's not give up at once
             (unless (plausible-bst-node-p thing)
               ;; It not even slightly plausible
               (return-from bst-p (values nil thing)))
             (multiple-value-bind (value left right)
                 (bst-node-components thing)
               (unless (funcall value-predicate value)
                 ;; Value is not legal
                 (return-from bst-p (values nil thing)))
               ;; check the ordering if the children are not null,
               ;; giving up promptly if they are not
               (when (not (null left))
                 (unless (funcall comparison-predicate
                                  (maybe-bst-value left)
                                  value)
                   (return-from bst-p (values nil thing))))
               (when (not (null right))
                 (unless (funcall comparison-predicate
                                  value
                                  (maybe-bst-value right))
                   (return-from bst-p (values nil thing))))
               value)))
    ;; It is slightly odd that the value is not used, but there is
    ;; nothing that says the value is not NIL
    (maybe-bst-value maybe-bst)
    (values t maybe-bst)))
```

And we can try this:

```
> (bst-p (make-consy-bst* '(8 (3 (1 () ())
                                 (6 (4 () ())
                                    (7 () ())))
                              (10 ()
                                  (14 (13 () ())
                                      ())))))
t
(8 (3 (1 nil) 6 (4 nil) 7 nil) 10 nil 14 (13 nil))

> (bst-p (make-consy-bst* '(8 (3 (1 () ())
                               (6 (4 () ())
                                  (7 () ())))
                            (10 ()
                                (14 (13 () ())
                                    (12 () ()))))))
nil
(14 (13 nil) 12 nil)
```

And you can see it's failing in the second case because the two children of the `14` node are not ordered.

---

**Note** this code is not tested, really, at all – I just typed it in mostly: there may be bugs.

Note also that in the first version of this I'd actually implemented a representation which was different than the one that I talked about.

Answer (score 0):

Please study this code:

```
(defun binary-search-tree-p (tree)
  (if (null tree)
    t
    (destructuring-bind (value &optional left right) tree
      (let ((left-val (car left))
            (right-val (car right)))
        (and (binary-search-tree-p left)
             (binary-search-tree-p right)
             (numberp value)
             (or (null left)
                 (<= left-val value))
             (or (null right)
                 (< value right-val)))))))
```

1. Naming: the function is clearly named, using the `-p` convention to indicate that it's a predicate: one-argument Boolean value to test some truth. The parameter is `tree`, not `list`. And by the way, in Common Lisp, `list` is a valid variable name which doesn't shadow the `list` function.
2. The null case is `T` rather than `NIL`. It greatly behooves us to declare that an empty BST is valid, rather than invalid.  If an empty BST is invalid, then if we want the one-node BST `(42 nil nil)`, to be valid, then we have to add ugly  arbitrary rules like that if a BST has empty children (which are themselves invalid!) then it is itself valid.
3. `destructuring-bind` with `&optional` simplifies the code for pulling apart the pieces of a tree node.
4. We validate that the children are `binary-search-tree-p` first. The next check is `(numberp value)`. Thus, if a tree is null, it is valid, but if it is not null, then it must have a numeric value.
5. Having settled some important questions in (4) above, we do not have to use `numberp` again. If we know that `left` is a valid BST, then if `left` isn't null, `(numberp left)` must be true because that was recursively checked!  We take advantage of this in the two remaining tests: `(or (null left) (<= (car left) value))`:  *"Either the left tree is empty, or else we can trust that left tree's value to be number, and that number must not exceed the value at this node"* and similarly for the right.
6. `(car left)` is safe if `left` is `nil`; however, it is important to acknowledge that our code will blow up on a tree node like `(42 "abc")` due to accessing `(car "abc")`. If it is required be robust against such a case, a bit of additional logic is required.
7. I'm assuming that  since you're using `<=`, duplicate values are obviously allowed in the tree. I'm further assuming that duplicate values run leftward. So that is to say, in the binary search, when the top-most duplicate value is encountered, the remaining duplicates of that value are all in the left subtree. This is easy to adjust so that the duplicates fall in the other direction, if required. However, note that under either choice, our test is needlessly strict. That is to say, this is actually a valid binary search tree with duplicates, which is rejected, because `(< 5 5)` fails on the right side:

   ```
         5
      5     5
     4 5      7
             6 8
   ```

   the proper conditions should be:

   ```
            ...
            (or (null left)
                (<= left-val value))
            (or (null right)
                (<= value right-val))
   ```